# mergExt mergSocket LiveCode

Tags: sockets, livecode

mergSocketAcceptConnections is causing my app to crash. I've successfully used mergSocket in the past. Is the latest mergSocket still compatible with later iOS versions?
iPad 1
iOS: 5.1.1
LiveCode: 6.7.6
mergSocket: 1.1.16

Comment: Can you open up a support ticket on mergExt with the crash log.

Comment: Crash report submitted on a new ticket.